# Frame is scrollable before scrollbar is activated

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, ttk

I was just trying the scrollbar widget and I encountered something weird. I saw this video on how to make an entire program scrollable and I just tweaked it to dynamically update the scrollregion of the canvas so that the scrollbar would adapt to the changes. One weird thing was that the scrollbar can scroll up before it is activated and push the content down. If you hit the up arrow it shoves the content aside and I don't want that. Also if you pack a couple of frames, enough for the scrollbar to activate, it won't do that. How can I fix this? My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

available_row = 1
root = Tk()
root.title("Scrollbar!")
root.geometry("500x320")
my_canvas = Canvas(root)


def add_fr_prg():
    global available_row
    lbl_fr = LabelFrame(second_frame, text=f"I am in row: {available_row}", padx=5, pady=5)
    prg = ttk.Progressbar(lbl_fr, length=300, orient=HORIZONTAL, mode="indeterminate")
    prg.pack()
    prg.start(9)
    lbl_fr.grid(row=available_row, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=3)
    available_row += 1


def scroll_up_down(event):
    my_canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * (int(event.delta / 120)), "units")


my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", scroll_up_down)
my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)
my_canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=second_frame, anchor='nw')
second_frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox('all')))
my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
add_btn = ttk.Button(second_frame, text="Add!", width=30, takefocus=False, command=add_fr_prg)
add_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=66)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scrollbar.get()` method returns a tuple. When there is no scroll bar it returns `(0.0 , 1.0)`. when the scroll bar is active it returns a tuple where the first number is >=0 and the second number is <=1.

so use this.

```py
def scroll_up_down(event):
    
    x, y = my_scrollbar.get()
    if x>0 or y < 1 : # or just if my_scrollbar.get() != (0.0, 1.0) :
        my_canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * (int(event.delta / 120)), "units")
```

Comment: I tried this @JacksonPro and for the binding it works but for the command of the scrollbar  my solution is not ideal and it has some problems. I would love it if you demonstrate how I can use this for both the command and the binf

Comment: @OmidKi I didn't quite get you. what do u mean by "for binding it works but for the command of the scrollbar my solution is not ideal and it has some problems"?

Comment: A ttk.Scrollbar only works with mouse clicks and mouse holds so I manually binded the <MouseWheel> event to the scroll_up_down function so that the user can use the scroll wheel to go up and down but when I defined the scrollbar I gave it a command of my_canvas.yview. So now in order to remove the bug I have to change it to my other function named scroll_up_down but with a scrollbar there are two modes "scroll" and "moveto". My question is there a better way to make the function work for both the "my_canvas.bind_all" and the "command" keyword of ttk.Scrollbar rather than checking the mode?

Comment: @OmidKi your current code works perfectly fine. I don't understand what kind of bug you are talking about.